# Regular expression that matches a string having alphabets or alphanumeric only

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am currently  using a regular expression that accepts only alphabets, like

```
 ?:[a-z][a-z]+
```

I have also used a regular expression that accepts alphanumeric but it does not meet my requirements

**My strings are in following pattern**

```
"john" or "john123"
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` ? or `/^[[:alnum:]]+$/` perhaps

Comment: Use `^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*$` However, you should explain the requirements. Are these strings starting with lowercase ASCII and then have 0+ digits?

Answer (score 1):

try `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`, this one works for me

Answer (score 1):

Try using this `^([A-Za-z]|[0-9])+$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(:?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]*)` '*non capturing*' or `([a-z0-9][a-z0-9]*)` '*capturing*'  in **case insensitive mode** to match alphanumeric words depending on whether you want to capture the words matched by regular expression.

Comment: what if the string becomes John123 ? should i change the expression to 
([a-Z0-9][a-Z0-9]*)

Comment: this is the right answers  second expression works for me

Comment: couldn't this just be `([a-z0-9]+)`

Comment: True. It can be `([a-z0-9]+)`, but I prefer that because of some inbuilt optimisation that some regex engines follow. They will check for initial `[a-z0-9]` which is required in regex, and stop execution if that is not found.

Answer (score 0):

this regular expression accept  alphabets  at the beginning of your String and  alphanumeric at the end
you can test it in https://regex101.com/

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: Why are you inserting underscore?

Comment: ohhh yes dont need    _  it is tue->   ^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$